# Firebase error, react

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firestore

Estoy intentando obtener un array de objetos que cree en Firestore. Array=listProducts.
intstale firebase, y cuando quiero obtener el array de objetos me tira este error

Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Expected first argument to collection() to be a CollectionReference, a DocumentReference or FirebaseFirestore

les paso el codigo, quizas alguno me pueda dar una pista..

ARCHIVO JS EN DONDE ME CONECTO CON FIREBASE

```
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app"
import {getFirestore} from "firebase/firestore"
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: //aca la direccion que me tira firestore para conectarme
  authDomain: "ecommerce-react-45765.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "ecommerce-react-45765",
  storageBucket: "ecommerce-react-45765.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "492631342338",
  appId: "1:492631342338:web:930000a3d325860bca961b"
}
// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

const db = getFirestore(app)//esto lo agrego yo
export default db//esto lo agrego yo
```

COMPLEMENTO DONDE LO QUIERO USAR

```
import React, {useState,useEffect} from "react"
import Item  from "./Item"
import {ProductsMock} from "../MockList/ProductsMock"//al definir asi, primero el archivo, despues la funcion, me deja llamar esa funcion
import { ClassNames } from "@emotion/react"
import{collection, getDocs} from "firebase/firestore"
import db from "../../Firebase/Firestore"
const ItemList=()=>{
    
    const[loading,setLoading]=useState(true)

    //2 declaro state parag uardar ahi lista que se obtiene del servidor
    const [listProductss,stateListProducts]=useState([])
  
    const getData= async ()=>{
        alert("ok")
        const getItems=collection(db,"listProducts")//ACA TIRA EL ERROR, NO RECONOCE EL DB
        
        const productsSnapshot=await getDocs(getItems)//devuelve array de objetos
        console.log(productsSnapshot, "snapsho")}
     




    useEffect(()=>{
        getData()
            
        },[])
    return(

        <div className="item-list">
            { loading?(
                <p>Cargando</p>
            ):(
            
            listProductss.map((product)=>{
                
                return <Item data={product} key={product.id}  /> 
                
            })
            )}


        </div>

    )

    }

    export default ItemList;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const q = query(collection(db, "users"));
getDocs(q)
```

getDocs recibe un query no un ref. Suerte